# Obtengo Inf como resultado de mean() en r

Tags: r

Tengo una tabla con varias variables, entre ellas una columna con el porcentaje de litros de agua consumidos. Estoy intentando calcular la media de ese porcentaje, pero obtengo como resultado `Inf`.

He intentado eliminar posibles Na con `mean(litros, na.rm=TRUE)`, pero sigo obteniendo el mismo resultado.

También he comprobado que tipo de variable es esa columna, porque anteriormente obtenía el siguiente error:

```
In mean.default(., litrosantes$litros, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

pero la variables sí es numeric.

Alguna solución?
Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

No es posible saberlo por completo sin esos datos, sin embargo lo más probable es que tu columna tenga valores `Inf`. Puedes verificarlo con la función `is.infinite()`, que te regresará `TRUE` para los valores `Inf`.

Ejemplo

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, Inf)

is.infinite(x)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

any(is.infinite(x))
[1] TRUE
```

En la última línea uso `any()`, que regresa `TRUE` si algún valor de un vector lógico es `TRUE`.

Puedes pasar ese `Inf` a `NA` facilmente:

```
x[is.infinite(x)] <- NA
```

Y luego procedes como lo habías hecho para descartar los `NA`.

De todos modos valdría la pena ver de dónde están saliendo ese `Inf`. Lo más probable es que haya alguna división por cero en un paso anterior del procesamiento de datos.